# Handwritten sources of first inventors

Tags: algorithms

When I was undergrad student, wondering how the inventor of the algorithm thinks like that. What was he/she writing out/drafting on papers/boards? I still cannot throw the thougt out the window, even after years. For example, Tony Hoare’s quickselect. I thought myself whether I could find 5th highest number in an array, I couldn’t. But he did. On the other hand, first inventor of tower of hanoi’s recursive solution. Some people claim that it is easy, don’t exaggerate it too much but I can’t agree with them. Or, Dijkstra’s handwrittrn notes?

Is there any platform that people can find the real notes? I really wonder how they feel when tackling the problems and how take steps toward solutions.

Comment: They probably didn't write the entire process; you will find only the end result. Research is a long and tough process, and the actual results of it are only 1% of the overall process.

Comment: @nirshahar yes, exactly. That’s why I seek 99% of it.

Comment: Most of it is probably not written anywhere, as "failed attempts" are almost never published.